# All nonisomorphic trees of order $n$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I have two questions regarding spanning trees:

> Q$1$. Is there any formula for the number of distinct trees of order $n$? I don't mean labelled trees, just distinct trees. For example: for $n=3$ there's only $1$ distinct tree, for $n=4$ there are $2$ distinct trees, for $n=6$ there are $6$.
>
> Q$2$. Is there any algorithm to implement the desired output in Q$1$?

Comment: There must be something pretty good: The [b-file](http://oeis.org/A000055/b000055.txt) at Sloane's A000055 gives the number of isomorphism classes on 1000 vertices!

Answer (score 3):

These numbers are the sequence [OEIS A000055](http://oeis.org/A000055); the link gives a fair bit of literature and a rather unpleasant-looking generating function, but no recurrence or closed form.

Comment: but what i'am asking for is formula to automatically count number of distict trees and generate the.

Comment: @HATEMEL-AZAB: And it appears that there isn’t one. If one were known, it would almost certainly appear in that OEIS link.