# What is the Number of Non Isomorphic Spanning trees of $K_n$? (Complete graph of size n)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So i know that for $K_6$ the answer is 6, but the book didn't explain how it solved this and i can't either!

so what is the Number of Non Isomorphic Spanning trees of $K_n$ ?

The only post related to this i found was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356300/all-nonisomorphic-trees-of-order-n) but there was no clear answer on there.

Comment: Yes i did actually find that thread before posting this, but there was no clear answer on there, maybe someone can come up with a equation here?

Comment: I find the existing answer to the duplicate very clear. What do you think is lacking in it?

Comment: Well i thought maybe someone can come up with a more clear answer here considering the website they linked looked like a webpage from 1999 and its really vague and badly written, but maybe i'm just not that smart.

Comment: The answer there links to OEIS which is pretty much the gold standard for references to integer sequences.